# How to host two Github Repositories on a single domain?

Tags: dns, subdirectory, github

I am using one Github repository to host a **portfolio website on the root** of my domain. Now I want a separate GitHub repository to host the **blog section** at the subdirectory of my domain "**www.example.com/blog**". How do I approach this?
I am using Publii as a CMS for my blog section.
My DNS settings are managed by Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty good article on this @ [Github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository). Basically you can set new origin in the sub directory "blog".

And you have some other options like submodules and subtrees. See the [answer @ Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039633/how-do-i-mount-one-github-repository-as-a-subfolder-of-another-repository).